# How can I round.max excel in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if there is a round.max Excel function but in JavaScript.

Tnx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Math.ceil(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

*Edit.* If you want to specify the precision, apply some basic math:

```
function roundup(x, digits) {
    var m=Math.pow(10, digits);
    return Math.ceil(x*m)/m;
}
```

---

Also see: [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

---

<s>If by "round.max" you meant `ROUND(MAX())`, then you'll want [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):</s>

```
Math.max(x, y, z, ...)
Math.max.apply(null, someArray)
```

Comment: nopep, I was looking for a ROUNDUP EXCEL FUNCTION BUT IN JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: @ingcarlos: Which does the same as `Math.ceil()`.

Comment: nop, Is not the same, the main reason is.... I need a function that supports floating numbers (numbers with decimals, and a really lot of decimals). I know you would tell me to use some basic arithmetical calculation, but MS Excel comes with that bundle in.

Comment: @ingcarlos: So JavaScript's `roundup()` is worse than Excel's simply because it is not "built in" to the language? (Excel was designed to work with lots of numbers, statistics, money, all that stuff. JavaScript is a generic language.)

Comment: I'm not saying that javascript is a bad language, I love it!, but Unfortunately there are not BigInteger solutions that came with that approach. According to your answer, I said is completely right, but for lower decimals numbers (I dont know the exact decimal numbers it can take... i assume max 17, and for what i need this is not the best solution), So I was looking for the same ceil plus lots of decimals numbers - BigInteger like - solution. I'm writting my own method to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish (I don't use Excel a lot), but [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) has an amazing database full of all the functions used in JavaScript. I would be very surprised if you didn't find what you are looking for, and quickly at [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com).

-Hope this helps! If you have any questions, let me know.

Comment: It seems weird, but the function I was looking for it hasn't been implemented yet. Really weird. mmm, and the other is that I made a mistake with excel function name, 'cause is not ROUND.MAX if not ROUNDUP. but tnx anyway.